# Selenium ide- how to simulate press keys ctrl-shift-delete to delete cookies?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, virtual-keyboard

When you manually press keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on your keyboard, you delete all cookies.

I use Selenium IDE and in my script I would like to automate deleting cookies by simulating pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, but I don't know what is the Command, Target and value to do that.

I don't want to use the `deleteCookie` command such as...

```
<tr>
    <td>deleteCookie</td>
    <td>__utmz</td>
    <td>path=/21910987/, domain=24hmontreal.canoe.ca, recurse=true</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you meant <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, right?

According to [the reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html), you need to call

[`controlKeyDown()`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#controlKeyDown)
[`shiftKeyDown()`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#shiftKeyDown)
[`keyPress("dom:document.body", "\127")`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#keyPress) // 127 being the ASCII code for Delete
[`shiftKeyUp()`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#shiftKeyUp)
[`controlKeyUp()`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#controlKeyUp)